# JS multidimensional array spacefield

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

i wanna generate a 3x3 field. I want to do this with JS, it shall be a web application.

All fields shall inital with false. But it seems so that my code is not working correctly, but i don't find my fault. The goal is, that every spacesector is accessible.

Thats my idea:

```
// define size
var esize = generateSpace(3);



}
```

Comment: You're creating a new array and storing it in `space[i]`, but then you're **overriding** that newly created array with the boolean value `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`space[i] = false` is replacing the array with a single boolean value `false`, not filling in all the entries in array you just created. You need another loop to initialize all the elements of the array.

```
function generateSpace(x) {
    var space = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        space[i] = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < x; j++) {
            space[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    return space;
}
```

Also, your `for()` loop condition was wrong, as you weren't initializing the last element of `space`. It should have been `i < space.length`.

And when it's done, it needs to return the array that it created.

Answer (score 0):

Since I got somewhat bored and felt like messing around, you can also initialize your dataset as shown below:

```
function generateSpace(x) {
    return Array.apply(null, Array(x)).map(function() {
        return Array.apply(null, Array(x)).map(function() {
            return false;
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other functions work equally well, but here's a fairly simply looking one using ES6 that works for any square grid:

```
function generateSpace(x) {
    return Array(x).fill(Array(x).fill(false));
}
```